# Why can't I use online features?

Tags: geometry-dash

Geometry Dash for me is completely up to date, my wifi is working just fine, I have deleted all my saved levels, and *still*, I can't use anything that requires Internet. I can't download any user levels, I can't open any daily chests, and I can't view my profile. Everything just shows that annoying 'spinny ring of doom'.

I playing the game on Windows 10.

Comment: I would say just check back later.  It appears to be a connectivity issue.

Answer (score 1):

there could be several things that are happening to you:

- your account could have been banned. these could be easily known just seeing your profile or your global ranking.
- maybe your internet connection is not working well
- another one is that robtop is having problems with the servers and is getting low on space so he is compressing all the files to have more space and that can cause some problems with the online features. the only way to solve this is to wait

to solve the banning problem you could try to wait or send an email to robtop.